# Undefined offset: 1 in AND Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am success to import email contact with yahoo Oauth API. And I can see that all my contact email is listed in the page when I echo it. However, while it success to print the email, there is an error message there :

`Trying to get property of non-object in globalses.php on line 295` AND 
`Undefined offset: 1 in globalses.php on line 295`

This is the code who shows that error:

```
  if (! empty($response)) {
    list($info, $header, $body) = $response;
    if ($body) {
      //logit("callcontact:INFO:response:");
      //print(json_pretty_print($body));
      $yahoo_array = json_decode($body);

     echo "<pre/>";
     //print_r($yahoo_array);
     foreach($yahoo_array as $key=>$values){


         foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub){
            // echo '<pre/>';
            // print_r($values_sub);
            // echo $values_sub->fields[1]->value->givenName;
             $email = $values_sub->fields[1]->value; //This is line 295

            if(trim($email)!="")
            $newList   .= $email.",";

         }
     }

    }
    $retarr = $newList."";
  }

  return $retarr;
```

**[UPDATE]** Th print result of `$values->contact`

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [isConnection] => 
        [id] => 50331977
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 50332026
                        [type] => email
                        [value] => academic_interlingua@cbn.net.id
                        [editedBy] => OWNER
                        [flags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [categories] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [categories] => Array
            (
            )

        [error] => 0
        [restoredId] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [isConnection] => 
        [id] => 41
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 63
                        [type] => email
                        [value] => access@sampoernafoundation.org
                        [editedBy] => OWNER
                        [flags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [categories] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [categories] => Array
            (
            )

        [error] => 0
        [restoredId] => 0
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [isConnection] => 
        [id] => 50331986
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 50332036
                        [type] => email
                        [value] => activeindonesia@yahoo.com
                        [editedBy] => OWNER
                        [flags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [categories] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 50332037
                        [type] => guid
                        [value] => APQMLKWC3QLQRAMYZQABSF63ZA
                        [editedBy] => OWNER
                        [flags] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Y360
                            )

                        [isConnection] => 
                        [categories] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [categories] => Array
            (
            )

        [error] => 0
        [restoredId] => 0
    )
```

**[UPDATE]**

```
         foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub){
            if(property_exists($values_sub, 'value') && !is_array($values_sub->value))


             //echo $values_sub->fields[1]->value->givenName;
             $email = $values_sub->fields[1]->value;

            if(trim($email)!="")
            $newList   .= $email.",";
```

[UPDATE] the result of var_dump

```
    academic_interlingua@cbn.net.idstring(31) "academic_interlingua@cbn.net.id"
    access@sampoernafoundation.orgstring(30) "access@sampoernafoundation.org"
    APQMLKWC3QLQRAMYZQABSF63ZAstring(26) "APQMLKWC3QLQRAMYZQABSF63ZA"
    activeindonesia@yahoo.comstring(25) "activeindonesia@yahoo.com"
    ade.nugraha@bisnis.co.idstring(24) "ade.nugraha@bisnis.co.id"
    IKN34TUEMHOJNOBUJQP5D2CBDQstring(26) "IKN34TUEMHOJNOBUJQP5D2CBDQ"
    adebete@yahoo.comstring(17) "adebete@yahoo.com"
    aditamiva.recruitment@gmail.comstring(31) "aditamiva.recruitment@gmail.com"
    admin@goodlife.co.idstring(20) "admin@goodlife.co.id"
    admin@klaudia.p.htstring(18) "admin@klaudia.p.ht"
    admin@l-cq.comstring(14) "admin@l-cq.com"
    admin@mujahidpress.comstring(22) "admin@mujahidpress.com"
    agoes@kesaintblanc.co.idstring(24) "agoes@kesaintblanc.co.id"
    agro.rekrutmen@agromediagroup.comstring(33) "agro.rekrutmen@agromediagroup.com"
```

Comment: What you get when you print_r($values->contact);  ??

Comment: Where should I print it?

Comment: above " foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub){ "

Comment: This seems `$values->contact` can't have sub-fields for all `$values` from `$yahoo_array`

Comment: It gives me an array: 

`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [isConnection] => 
            [id] => 50331977
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 50332026
                            [type] => email
                            [value] => academic_interlingua@cbn.net.id
                            [editedBy] => OWNER

Comment: @alisa Can you please update the question by printing the result on question itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the email by its fields as:

```
 $email = $values_sub->fields[1]->value; //This is line 295
```

When you see the first element of an array, there is no any fields with key 1, since it is only value in the array. `$fields[0].`

By seeing your code and the actual array, i come up with the following, this may not be the complete solution, but hope guides towards the result.

So this must be something like this:

```
foreach($values->contact as $keys=>$values_sub){
            $fields = $values_sub->fields;
            foreach($fields as $field){
                if(property_exists($field,'value') && !is_array($field->value)){
                    echo (string) $field->value;
                  }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But I am sorry, I am confused, I don't know how to implement this or where to put this. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I hope you are clear about the error. You are always accessing the `$values_sub->fields[1]` . Try iterate over the fields rather than accessing them as you have done.

Comment: When I change fields[1] into fields[0] I come with this error: `trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in globalses.php on line 301 which it is in `if(trim($email)!="") . . .`

Comment: @alisa Dont do that. You are not dealing with just one, but arrays. So, have to iterate over the array of fields, as i answered.

Comment: But I still don't know how to fix this with your code. I am just thinking how to just hide this error message?

Comment: See my last update where I implement your code there.

Comment: @alisa I dont have any editor to run this for you. I have updated my answer. You can just try something like that.

Comment: Now I got this error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in globalses.php on line 296 which it is in `echo (string) $field->value;`

Comment: Try `echo "{$field->value}"` . Or just `print_r($field->value)` it to see if you have actual result or not.

Comment: I have the actual result which it is echoing all the email contacts. But still there is the error message of `could not be converted to string in globalses.php on line 296` which it is in echo "{$field->value}";

Comment: Introduce keys and values to foreach on $fields and try the same.